# Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: python, django

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'accounts.views.new_fn' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'student_pk': *********}' not found.
(asterisks are actually numbers, I just redacted them).

Anyway, I can't quite figure out why this isn't working. In googling this error it seems this comes from not have urls defined properly, however, I can't see how that is so! As usual, your help is appreciated!

from urls.py

```
 (r'^lockers/(?P<course_pk>\w+)/$', 'lockers'),
 (r'^lockers/(?P<course_pk>\w+)/assignlocker/$', 'lockerassign'),
```

from views.py

```
 @user_is_valid
 def lockers(request, course_pk):
     print("Lockers - A")
     course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=course_pk)
     students =       Student.objects.filter(--redacted, but this does work)
print("Render to Response - B")
return render_to_response("accounts/locker_roster.html", {'students':students, 'lockers':orderedlockers}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


 @user_is_valid
 def lockerassign(request,student_pk):
if request.method == "POST":
    print("Method is Post - C")
    pass
else:
    print("Render form - D")
    lockers = Locker.objects.raw(sql query, which does in fact work)
    student = Student.object.get(pk=student_pk)
    print("Render to Response - E")
    return render_to_response("accounts/locker_assign.html",{'student':student , 'lockers':lockers} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

from locker_roster.html

```
 {%for student in students%}
             <tr>
                <td>{{student}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                  <a href="{% url accounts.views.lockerassign student_pk=student.pk%}">Assign Locker</a>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         {%endfor%}
```

Note: google chrome marks the error being in an iteration of students.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `{% url %}` tag, you need to add the `name` property to your urls for Django to be able to reverse them:

```
(r'^lockers/(?P<course_pk>\w+)/$', name='lockers'),
(r'^lockers/(?P<course_pk>\w+)/assignlocker/$', name='lockerassign'),
```

To test if you have reversed them correctly use: [`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse).

Answer (score 0):

Having given the URL a `name` attribute in your urlconf, you need to use that name, rather than the function path, to reverse it.

```
{% url lockerassign student_pk=student.pk %}
```

(I presume from the fact that you didn't use quotes originally that you are using Django <1.5. If you are on a higher version, you should put the view name in quotes.)